# Is it possible to pass types defined in plsql package headers using odp.net?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, odp.net

```
  TYPE point IS RECORD (
  X NUMBER,  -- The X co-ordinate of the point
  Y NUMBER   -- The Y co-ordingate of the point
  );
```

This is defined in my package header. It is then used in a procedure defined in the same package. Is it possible for me to call the procedure via ODP.net?

Comment: essentially i have an array of 2d points in my application and I want to pass them to a pl/sql stored procedure within a package. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: It turns out you can't pass the record type using odp.net. Something to do with limitations in the language its written in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can pass a record, but the article about [Using PL/SQL Associative Arrays](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/07-jan/o17odp.html)  might help.

The author uses two arrays to pass `min_salary` and `max_salary`, you should be able to do the same with `x` and `y`.